# does quotient map distribute over union

Tags: general-topology

Let $X = A \bigcup\limits_{f} B$ an adjunction space with $f:M \rightarrow A$ and $M \subset B$. If I have a quotient map $q: X \rightarrow X/E $ where $E \subset A$, is it generally true that the following holds:

$q(X) = q(A) \bigcup\limits_{\overline{f}}B$ where $\overline{f} = q \circ f$. How should I prove this statement.

Comment: You can use the pasting law for pushouts. i.e. the second part of [Proposition 2.1](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pasting+law+for+pullbacks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to write $X = B \cup_f A$ since $A$ is attached to $B$ via $f$. But that it is matter of taste. We know that $X$ is given as the pushout
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
B @>{f'}>> X\\
@A{i}AA @A{j}AA\\
M @>{f}>> A\end{CD}
where $i: M \to B$ denotes inclusion. Concerning pushouts and adjunction spaces see for example tom Dieck's "General Topology", especially Proposition (1.8.1).

The map $j$ is an embedding, thus we may regard $A$ as a subpace of $X$. If $E \subset A$, then we have a quotient map $\bar q : A \to A/E$. Consider the pushout

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X @>{\bar q'}>> P\\
@A{j}AA @A{j'}AA\\
A @>{\bar q}>> A/E\end{CD}

On the level of **sets** we clearly have $P = X/E$ and $\bar q' = q : X \to X/E$. But since $\bar q$ is a quotient map, also $\bar q'$ is one and we see that $\bar q' = q$ on the level of topological spaces. Thus $j'$ is an embedding and we may identify $A/E$ with $q(A)$.

It is well-known (and easy to prove) that the composition of two pushout squares is again a pushout square. Therefore

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
B @>{qf'}>> X/E \\
@A{i}AA @A{j'}AA\\
M @>{qf}>> q(A) \end{CD}
is a pushout square which answers your question.